# BufferedImage in IKVM

Tags: java, .net, bufferedimage, ikvm, notimplementedexception

What is the best and/or easiest way to replace the missing `BufferedImage` functionality for a Java project I am converting to .NET with IKVM?

I'm basically getting "`cli.System.NotImplementedException`: *BufferedImage*" exceptions when running the application, which otherwise runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

The AWT code in IKVM is fairly easy to read and edit.  I'd recommend you look for the methods that you are using that throw that exception, and then implement them.  I've done this several times before with IKVM's AWT implementation and found it easy to do for background/server related functions.  Its much less usable if your app is a desktop app, however.

Comment: If you do so, please submit it to the IKVM project.